# How to calculate and display ratings for font-awesome using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I am trying to display the stars and append the `<i>` tag dynamically based on the count.

It's working fine, but the problem is if it has floating value then it displays the star in full, I need the star to be half (CSS class `fa-star-half-o`).

This is what I tried:

```js
var ratingValue = 3.489;

for (var j = 0; j < ratingValue; j++) {
  $(".rating").append('<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rating">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have half star in your font collection?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Yes, <i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/32L669tv/5/

Comment: If you're looking for a non-jQuery solution, just put 5 stars in a div and set the divs width to whatever your rating is, percentage-wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve what you want like below,

```
var ratingValue = 3.489, rounded = (ratingValue | 0);
var decimal = ratingValue - rounded, $rating = $(".rating");

for (var j = 0; j < rounded ; j++) {
   $rating.append('<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}

if(decimal) {
  $rating.append('<i class="fa fa-star-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/32L669tv/6/)

Edit as per your new requirement,

### There is no need for 2 different for loops (simple math is enough)

```
var ratingValue = 3.9, rounded = (ratingValue | 0);

for (var j = 0; j < 5 ; j++) {
  $(".rating").append(
         '<i class="fa '+ ((j < rounded) 
                  ? "fa-star" 
                  : ((((ratingValue - j) > 0) && ((ratingValue - j) < 1)) 
                     ? "fa-star-half-o" 
                     : "fa-star-o")) 
         +'" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/32L669tv/10/)

And to make the code more readable, we can do like this,

```
var ratingValue = 1.9,
  rounded = (ratingValue | 0),
  str;

for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  str = '<i class="fa ';
  if (j < rounded) {
    str += "fa-star";
  } else if ((ratingValue - j) > 0 && (ratingValue - j) < 1) {
    str += "fa-star-half-o";
  } else {
    str += "fa-star-o";
  }
  str += '" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
  $(".rating").append(str);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/32L669tv/13/)

Comment: Almost perfect! I guess _"if it has floating value"_ == anything > 0

Comment: I always want to show 5 stars, in this scenario the 5th star should be displayed as empty. Can you please add that too. I forgot to mention that

Comment: @M-S Updated the answer. Have a look at it now.

Comment: Nested ternery operators withs loads of parenthesis make code completely unreadable.

Comment: @BadHorsie And I made the code more readable now. Is that ok to remove your downvote? :)

Answer (score 4):

try using some math

```
var ratingValue = 3.489;
var roundedValue = Math.trunc(ratingValue);

for (var j = 0; j < roundedValue; j++) {
  $(".rating").append('<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
var k = 0;
if (ratingValue -roundedValue  > 0.4 && ratingValue -roundedValue < 1) {
  k = 1;
  $(".rating").append('<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
for (var i = Math.trunc(ratingValue)+k; i < 5; i++) {
  $(".rating").append('<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8vmbc1a7/4/

Comment: Do you not think that place Math.round(ratingValue) outside the loop will increase the performance of execution

Answer (score 3):

If `j <= ratingValue` add a full star, else if `j < ratingValue + 1` add a half-star, else add an empty star.

```js
var ratingValue = 3.489;

for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
  $(".rating").append('<i class="fa fa-star' + ((j <= ratingValue) ? '' : ((j < ratingValue + 1) ? '-half-o' : '-o')) + '" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="rating">
</div>
```

Comment: I always want to show 5 stars, in this scenario the 5th star should be displayed as empty. Can you please add that too. I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1):

updated your fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/32L669tv/2/` take a look.

The code:

```
var ratingValue = 3.489;
var intRatingVal = parseInt(ratingValue);

for(var j=0; j < intRatingVal; j++){
  $(".rating").append( '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>' );
}

if ((ratingValue - intRatingVal) > 0) {
    $(".rating").append( '<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>' );
}
```

The basic thing is -- if there are floating number in rating -- you don't need a single loop to show half star. just show full star based on full part and then half based on if there are any floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can round down the value and calculate the difference between the rounded value and the actual rating value:   `var dif = ratingValue - roundValue`

- if `dif > 0.5` display a full star
- if `0.5 > dif > 0.1` display a half star
- if `dif < 0.1` no additional stars displayed

  ```
  var ratingValue = 3.489;
  var floorVal = Math.floor(ratingValue);
  for(var j=0; j<floorVal; j++){
     $(".rating").append( '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>' );
  }
  var dif = ratingValue - floorVal;
  if(dif  > 0.5)
  {
     $(".rating").append( '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>' )
  }
  else if(dif > 0.1)
  {
     $(".rating").append( '<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>' );
  }
  ```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32L669tv/8/)